# Python, Bottle, MongoDB Create Function 500 Error Code

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, bottle

I am creating a REST service using Bottle and MongoDB. The problem is I am getting a 500 error code when trying to insert a document.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Error: 500 Internal Server Error</title>
            <style type="text/css">
              html {background-color: #eee; font-family: sans;}
              body {background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #ddd;
                    padding: 15px; margin: 15px;}
              pre {background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Error: 500 Internal Server Error</h1>
            <p>Sorry, the requested URL <tt>&#039;http://localhost:8080/create&#039;</tt>
               caused an error:</p>
            <pre>Unhandled exception</pre>
        </body>
    </html>
```

cURL

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id" : "10011-2017-TEST","certificate_number" : 9278833,"business_name" : "ACME TEST INC.","date" : "Feb 20 2017","result" : "No Violation Issued","sector" : "Test Retail Dealer - 101"}' http://localhost:8080/create
```

The thing is though, I am able to successfully insert a document even though I get the 500 error code. Why am I getting the 500 error code? I have been trying to implement exception handling for both MongoDB and Bottle. Not sure if that is why I am getting the code. If not, how can I properly implement exception handling? I have read up on abort but I have had trouble with that. Also, when I comment out `return result` , I get a 200 response code, but I want to return the id of the document inserted. Thanks

Source Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bson import json_util
import json
import bottle
from bottle import route, run, request, abort, post, error
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime as datetime

connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection['city']
collection = db['inspections']


@route('/create', method='POST')
def insert_document():

    try:
        data = request.json
        result = collection.insert_one(data).inserted_id
    except Exception, e:

        print ('EXCEPTION: ', e)

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':

    run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    return result
```

to

```
    return str(result)
```

or simply remove the line altogether.

Comment: So the 500 error was because the result was not a string? Also what about Bottle error handling? Is there any reason to add abort?

Comment: I'm not familiar with bottle but as a guess it was interpreting the id as a non-zero return code hence raising that 500